# How do I make a VS project template appear in a sub-folder?

Tags: visual-studio-extensions

Currently my VS 2013 project template is appearing in the "Visual C#" folder of the Add New Project dialog. How can I move it into a subfolder of that dialog?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to physically create a new folder inside the template folder and move the template into it. For example:

```
C:\Users\jonathanallen\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual C#\My Templates
```

Still looking for an option that doesn't rely on the users happening to put the file in the right place. Maybe a VSIX package?